# PHP Looking for a function that gets values from a string

Tags: php, arrays, regex, function, output

I'm looking for a function in PHP that can get only the numbers preceded by "**ACTIVE-**" out of this string BUT leaving out those preceded by "**CATEGORY-ACTIVE-**"

```
 $product_req = "ACTIVE-6,CATEGORY-ACTIVE-8,CATEGORY-ACTIVE-4,ACTIVE-9";
```

I tried with `preg_match_all` but it wont work because that returns all of the numbers. What function should I use instead?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative look-behind `?<!-` for the Hyphen , If a hyphen is found before the word `ACTIVE` then it won't be matched.

```
<?php
$str = 'ACTIVE-6,CATEGORY-ACTIVE-8,CATEGORY-ACTIVE-4,ACTIVE-9';
preg_match_all('/(?<!-ACTIVE-)(\d+)/', $str, $matches);
echo implode(',',$matches[1]);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
6,9
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's just a matter of good regex:

```
$re = '/(^|,)ACTIVE-(\d+)/'; 
$str = 'ACTIVE-6,CATEGORY-ACTIVE-8,CATEGORY-ACTIVE-4,ACTIVE-9'; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

Matches **6** and **9**

**Regex explaination:**

1. First brackets match either line string start (the `^` char) or comma. This way we get rid of `CATEGORY-`.
2. Second brackets match your number as `\d` stands for digit character and `+` for one or more.
3. `g` at end means `global` flag - don't stop after first match.

You can read more about PHP regex syntax here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html

You can play with this regex here: http://regex101.com/r/yD6xJ0

Comment: thanks that works but i would appreciate an explanation because i really dont quite understand the $re part. Why are all those weird symbols necessary? What do they mean?

Comment: @CainNuke added explanation and some useful links